# How to set AND get my array to access throughout my app using a class?

Tags: objective-c

I have an app that needs to access customers from the DB. I've got the array of data but I need to share it in a few views within my app.

I created this class called Customers but I'm not sure how to call and set/get my `NSMutableArray` of customers.

Is there a good example or maybe a code snippet that someone can show me?

```
#import "Customers.h"

@implementation Customers

 static NSMutableArray *customers; 
 // I need to set/access the customers array class from all views.

 + (NSMutableArray *)allCustomers 
 {
  if !(customers) 
  {
   customers = [NSMutableArray array];
  }
  return customers;
 }
 @end
```

Comment: I don't understand the question.  And the code part needs editing (there are some lines outside the gray box).

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you read about the singleton pattern. Using the singleton pattern, you make sure a class is initialized once, and persisted. In that way, you can easily reach this class from anywhere, and in that way get and set its array from any class.

Singletons in obj-c: http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/singleton-classes/

It would look something like this:

interface:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *customers;

+ (Customers *)sharedCustomers;
```

implementation:

```
+ (Customers *)sharedCustomers
{
    static Customers *sharedCustomers;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedCustomers= [[Customers alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedCustomers;
}
```

Then from anywhere, by importing "Customers.h", you can get and set the array.

Getting:

```
[[Customers sharedCustomers] customers];
```

Setting:

```
[[Customers sharedCustomers] setCustomers:...];
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are using the class object as a singleton, to grant access to a file-private variable.

You could go ahead and add (class) methods to:

1. Read the database from file/network or wherever it is
2. Search the array

e.g.

```
+ (id) customerAtIndex:(NSUInteger) index
{
    return [customers objectAtIndex:index];
    // (perhaps you can add a bounds check)
}

+ (void) insertCustomer:(id) customer atIndex:(NSUInteger) index
{
    [customers insertObject:customer atIndex:index];
    // (perhaps you can add a bounds check)
}
```